# Find command can't find my files?

Tags: find

I have Vesta Control Panel on my Ubuntu server and its serving my websites fine. I can even FTP into the sites to update files as necessary.

So when I connect via FTP, I can browse to Remote Site:

> /public_html/sma/modules/pos/views

Here I see the file `view.php` so clearly this file exists somewhere on my server, right?

Switch over to terminal and I execute these commands which don't return any results:

```
sudo find ~/ -iname "view.php"
sudo find / -iname "view.php"
```

No results would seems to indicate that there is no file called view.php anywhere on my system which clearly can't be the case since I can CRUD the file through Filezilla over FTP.

What is going on!?

Answer (score 2):

You are searching in your home directory only by `~/`.

To search in the root directory and all subdirectories recursively i.e. throughout the system:

```
sudo find / -iname "view.php"
```

Also as you are looking for a file, you should specify the file type with `-type` option to make the command efficient:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "view.php"
```

Also you should exclude the virtual filesystem mount points, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev` and `tmpfs` mount point `/run` from search:

```
sudo find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /dev -o \
               -path /run \) -prune -o -type f -iname 'view.php'
```

Comment: Are you sure that last command is correct? I got an error when I tried `sudo find / -type f -iname 'view.php' \( -path /proc -o -path /sys \ -o -path /dev \) -prune -o -print
find: paths must precede expression:  -o
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`

Comment: @Ortund The "\" at teh end of first line is to make the command multi-line for readability here. In one line:  `sudo find / -type f -iname 'view.php' \( -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /dev \) -prune -o -print`

Comment: so many results all out of /sys/ and /run/ ... at least the ones I can still scroll up to

Comment: @Ortund Exclude `/run` too, check my edits..also there should not be any from `/sys`

Comment: if it is finding my folders I can't tell because its finding a LOT of stuff and I can't scroll through it all. This image is just 1 screen of results from this command -> http://i.imgur.com/kf5V4Oi.png

Comment: @Ortund Oops..my bad..please run the edited command..

Comment: Edited command? In comment or answer?

Comment: @Ortund In answer, here it is anyway: `sudo find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /dev -o -path /run \) -prune -o -type f -iname 'view.php'`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo find /public_html -iname view.php
```

In your `find` invocation, you are searching a different directory than what you show as the directory containing `view.php`.  (It *may* be that the `views` directory is visible under both `/public_html/` and your home directory `~` via symlinks, but this is not clear from what you have posted.)

Comment: Does `find ~/ ...` not search the entire file system?

Comment: `~` refers to your home directory; typically `/home/yourname/`

Comment: okay but `find / -iname view.php` which I believe refers to the entire filesystem doesn't return any results either